# Button perform action from another file (Swift)

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitextview

I would like to tap a UIButton to clear a UITextView. I would like the code for the button's action to be in another Swift file. How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: By "in another Swift file" do you mean in a different view controller, or just in a separate .swift text file that extends the same view controller?

Comment: Yes. Just a separate .swift text file for the buttons action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your button actions to be in a different Swift file, just create a class `extension` for your `ViewController` in the new file:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

**ViewControllerExt.swift**

```
import UIKit

extension ViewController {
    @IBAction func coolButton(sender: UIButton) {
        println("cool button pressed")
        myTextField.text = "cool"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this code go in the new ViewControllerExt.swift or in the ViewController.swift?

Comment: This code goes in the new ViewControllerExt.swift file.

Comment: There is an error message that says "Declaration is only valid at file scope"

Comment: You can define functions in the extensions, but not new properties.  The `var`s and `let`s need to be in the main file.  You will be able to access them in the extension.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have the UITextView declared in ViewController.swift and the code above in ViewControllerExt.swift. The error is on the line of the `extension ViewController {`

Comment: I added my ViewController.swift file.  I added a text field and the button fills it in.  This all compiles and works.

Comment: if that was about a different file ..this is not the way to do it.creating an extension means you are inside the class

Comment: I asked that question to the OP. See comments below the original question. They wanted it to be in a separate .swift file, but still a part of the same viewController.